# Customize Error Bar plot in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

Please consider :

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];

list = {{223, 231, 167, 245, 292}, {90, 81, 88, 84, 106}}
```

Where the second list represent the StandardDeviation

```
 ErrorListPlot[list // Transpose,                   
               PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 500}}]
```

[image]

I find it very hard to customize those ErrorList Plot. So my ugly attempt to avoid using the package and achieve the filling I wanted :

```
ListPlot[{(list[[1]] - list[[2]]), (list[[1]] +
           list[[2]]), list[[1]]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Questions :

Is there an " efficient" way to adjust the appearance using ErrorListPlot ? 
If not How would you suggest handling error bar using ListPlot or BarChart ?

I have to mention that I use Joined so as to increase the visibility but, each point represent a different subject so they should not be but : Using ErrorListPlot I could not make the mean visible enough :-(

EDIT : @Sjoerd

[image]

Comment: I think you are meant to plot a whole standard deviation above and below the points, not half as you have done in the second graph.

Comment: I don't think your graph format is very common in scientific reporting, or isn't that your goal?

Comment: If you like confidence bands to be drawn around your data you might want to look at `NonlinearModelFit`, specifically the 'Application' section.

Comment: @Sjoerd, you are touching my very problem those days. I have some nice data and results. I thought the job was done. I have never done any scientific writing of any kind, nor did I read a lot of articles in my field "to stay fresh".And now owe a paper since last Friday :-( If you saw the plot I had prepared originally you would laugh for a while... For each measure I make I need to show the group result as well as the result for each subjects. If you have some advises, they are more than welcome. I think you know the field pretty well :-)

Comment: @Sjoerd, "NonlinearModelFit" really seems relevant here, thank you for that trick.

Comment: @Sjoerd, please see the edit. I really thought that was relevant/publishable plot. I guess scientific writing is closer to a formal language. I will soon ask for some help on how to use web mathematica. Like this I could always show what I want.

Comment: @500 - I only just saw your edit. This is doable in Mathematica, but personally I would not recommend the grey background for a plot intended for a journal. It will not necessarily reproduce well. White backgrounds and minimal "ink" always reveal the story better. I wasn't sure whether those big blue dots and their colours meant anything, or if they were just dots. I really recommend you have a look at any of the books by Edward Tufte - they are seminal discussions of the graphical presentation of numerical data.

Comment: @Verbeia, Yeah I know those plots are just ridiculous. Thank You for the "Edward Tufte " recommendation, relay inspiring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Filling` with a normal ListPlot, not joined, to get  vertical lines rather than area filling. Then style the dots as you like with `PlotStyle`. But also check out some of the options to `ErrorListPlot`. There are options to do what you need.

```
ErrorListPlot[list // Transpose, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 500}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[14], AbsoluteThickness[2]}]
```

According to the documentation, `ErrorListPlot` takes all the same options as `ListPlot`.

[image]